# Does a std::map lock its nodes to prevent other processes from deleting them?

Tags: c++, locking, stdmap, plc

i got a serious problem here. 
I have got two different tasks (like a process) running on my PLC X20 form B&R accessing one singleton object "VarList". Its purpose is to allow interprocess communication via pointers.

Task A is creating the object which includes a std::map by using a static getInstance() Method. There the pointer if that object is assigned to a global PLC variable to allow access from every Task to that specific object. That task is also checking every task cycle for an insertion of a variable into that map. In which case it tries to delete that inserted node again, just for testing purpose.

Task B gets the pointer of the object to via the getInstance method and inserts a bool* into the map.

Afterwards Task A tries to delete it again and it crashes with a access violation. I can access the Nodes and its values. I can change that values. But erasing a node created in a different task results in a crash, and i would like to know why!

The PLC is singlethreaded, so there should be no concurrent access to the memory.

Is this a locking problem? Or is this a logic problem? A STL Problem? A Null pointer Problem? Or maybe again a problem of the specific implementation for the std library of the plc vendor? Any help related to the accessviolation is appreciated!

Here are the code snippets of the mentioned Object, i removed everything not related to the problem, just to get a hint. sorry, its most likely not compileable:

Compiler: gcc 4.1.2

### Task A:

```
#include <VarListe.hpp>
VarListe::Ptr VLInstanz;

void _INIT VLErzeugerInit(void)
{
    VLInstanz = VarListe::getInstance("VLErzeuger");
}

void _CYCLIC VLErzeugerCyclic(void)
{
    VLInstanz->checkNewVars(); // Access Violation here
}
```

### Task B:

```
#include <VarListe.hpp>
VarListe::Ptr vals;

bool setPtr = true;


void _INIT VarListeTestInit(void)
{
}

// btn_VarTest is a Boolean plc Variable for a button on the Visu
void _CYCLIC VarListeTestCyclic(void)
{
    try
    {
        if(btn_VarTest &&setPtr) 
        {
            vals = VarListe::getInstance("VarListe1");
            vals->setVar("btn_VarTest",&btn_VarTest);   
            //vals->checkNewVars(); // Works perfect if used here. Thats not the point
            setPtr = false;
        }
    catch (...)
    {
    }
}
```

### VarListe.hpp

```
#include <map>
#include <deque>
#include <string>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

using namespace std;

class VarListe
{
    public: 

    typedef bool*           BoolPtr;

    typedef boost::shared_ptr<VarListe> Ptr;

    static Ptr getInstance(string owner);
    static Ptr _alwaysUseGetInstance;
    static char owners[200];

    void checkNewVars();

    private:
    typedef map<string, BoolPtr >           BoolPtrMap;

    typedef deque<BoolPtrMap::iterator>     BoolVarQueue;
    BoolVarQueue                            _boolVarQueue;

    BoolPtrMap      _boolListe;

    public:
    void setVar(string key, bool* value);
};
```

### VarListe.cpp

```
#include <VarListe.hpp>

VarListe::Ptr VarListe::_alwaysUseGetInstance; // Singleton static Variable; used olny by the object creator
char    VarListe::owners[200]; // just to test which task creats the object

#include <../../Temp/Includes/globalvar.h> // For the global PLC variable 'GlobalVarListe' 

// This static Method runs perfectly, no need to check here
VarListe::Ptr VarListe::getInstance(string owner)
{

    if(GlobalVarListe == 1337)
    {
        strcpy(VarListe::owners, "");
        owner += "(Builder)";
        if (!VarListe::_alwaysUseGetInstance)
            VarListe::_alwaysUseGetInstance = VarListe::Ptr(new VarListe);
        GlobalVarListe = (UDINT) &VarListe::_alwaysUseGetInstance;
        VarListe::_alwaysUseGetInstance->setVar("VarListOwners",VarListe::owners);
    }
    VarListe::Ptr tempVL = *( (VarListe::Ptr*) GlobalVarListe);
    VarListe::CharPtrPair locOwners;
    if(tempVL->assertVar("VarListOwners",locOwners))
    {
        string temp = string(locOwners.first);
        temp = temp + owner + " + ";
        strcpy(locOwners.first, temp.c_str());
    }

    return tempVL;
}

// This Method is used in Task B
void VarListe::setVar(string key, bool* value)
{
    pair<BoolPtrMap::iterator, bool > eingetragen;
    eingetragen = _boolListe.insert(pair<string, BoolPtr>(key, value ));

    if(eingetragen.second == false)
    {
    } 
    else
        _boolVarQueue.push_back(eingetragen.first);
}

// This method is in Task A
void VarListe::checkNewVars()
{
    if(!_boolVarQueue.empty())
    {
        string key = _boolVarQueue.front()->first;  //OK, 
        BoolPtr bp = _boolVarQueue.front()->second; //OK
        _boolVarQueue.front()->second = 0;          //OK
        _boolListe[key] = bp;                       //OK
        BoolPtrMap::iterator fund = _boolListe.find(key); // OK
        if (fund != this->_boolListe.end())         // OK
        {       
            _boolListe.erase(key);                      //Access Violation: Code 9101 only if used by Task A 
            _boolListe.erase(_boolVarQueue.front());    //Access Violation: Code 9101 
            _boolListe.erase(fund);                     //Access Violation: Code 9101
        }
        _boolVarQueue.pop_front();                  //OK
        _boolListe[key] = bp;                       //OK    
    }
}
```

### Thanks!

Comment: Why use pointer to `bool`? It would be _much_ simpler to just store the `bool` directly. When using primitive types, there are almost no use of having pointers to them.

Comment: Pretty sure you can chop this down to a smaller example: See [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Joachim i know what u mean, but my intentions are to share a specific memory location with several processes. thats why its a pointer.

Comment: do these separate tasks have separate address spaces ?

Comment: Are the tasks _real_ multitasking tasks, i.e. they can be pre-empted at any time? Then yes you need some kind of protection. If the tasks are sequential or the multitasking is cooperative, then it might not be needed.

Comment: @PeterWood its actually nearly the minimalistic version thats compiling for my plc showing that error. I didnt even needed to add that information to get my answer as Mats Petersson answered my question to my content. I just wanted to be complete.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker AFAIK they share a common space, but my experience show its not always true. 
@ JoachimPileborg they are 100% sequential

Answer (score 2):

Placing an STL map in any kind of shared memory between processes (or tasks) with separate address spaces cannot be done reliably without changes.

The problem is that if process A inserts data into the map, it will allocate any new memory from its own address space (and maps do allocate memory internally for new entries), which is not accessible from process B. So, if process B then tries to access that newly inserted data, it's very likely to get an error (eg. an access violation).

Fortunately, the STL containers allow to override the allocator to replace it with your own. If your own allocator then ensures it allocates memory from the shared memory rather than the process' own address space, then things should work better.

Comment: Interesting point, i never used the allocator so far, maybe that would solve my problems. I'll dig into it now. Thanks!

Comment: If there is any chance of concurrent access to the map, you will also have to add locking as per the other answer. If you can guarantee that every operation on the map is done "atomically" (ie. a task fully completes its operation before any other task does anything with the map), this should not be needed.

Comment: As i said, the task are completly sequential, and for development purpose i can ensure that this operations are done "atomically", so thats not the problem so far. Later when everything is put together there might be a chance of a task gets suspended while accessing the map, but i am aware of that kind of problems. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1):

The standard implementation does not have/require any locking:

http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/thread_safety.html

It is of course permissible for an implementation to include locks, should it wish to do so.

Comment: Well, i read in that document, that there seems to be some sort of locking within the allocators. This may lead to exact my problems, as i am only unable to erase a node created by another thread. But i am not sure... I am not experiencing any other problems accessing memory of other threads

Comment: Right, an access violation is probably not due to locking. It is much more likely that you are trying to use memory allocated in a different task (as hinted above), and the memory simply doesn't belong to the currently running process.

Comment: I just read about boost interprocess allocators, which may solve my problems. i ll ask another question tomorrow about it.